# Regex to restrict list of guids to specific options

Tags: regex, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a sitecore template field which I want to restrict to one or more or the following guids. They can appear in any order and will be pipe separated.

- {7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef}
- {57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f}
- {c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701}
- {97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520}

So far I have this regex, but this needs to FAIL if any other text other than the above guids and the separating pipes is entered.

`[\|]?\{(7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef|57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f|c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701|97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520)\}`

How can I get this working as described?

I'm using sitecore, so I assume we are using .net regex here but it is difficult to tell :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little bit of modification to your expression to get it to work:

```
^(?:\||(?:\{(?:7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef|57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f|c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701|97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520)\}))*$
```

I have added the anchors `^` and `$` to match the start-of-line and end-of-line respectively.

I have also added the `*` to entire grouping to support one or more of your GUIDs on the same line.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW9vX1)

Comment: Non-capturing group `?:` FTW! I had tried ^ and $ bookends but the grouping was off. Lovely stuff, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try ^ (line start) and $ (line end)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^\{(7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef|57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f|c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701|97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520)\}([\|]?\{(7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef|57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f|c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701|97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520)\})*$
```

Here I have added `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the string. Also, I have repeated the wanted strings for the first time and put the other one into a group. Then that group is repeated 0 to infinite times.

```
^\([\|]?\{(7f05059e-4b4c-4d4d-bb39-1f57446719ef|57cb8e77-30cb-4dba-88bb-104cfea2e94f|c41ac6b6-a5c9-47f9-86c2-7db9e861e701|97133d89-36a1-4c28-9f30-4516eb469520)\})+$
```

This is a shorter version, but allows an extra pipe in the beginning of the string.